# Somar os valores dentro das tags XML com C#

Tags: c#, xml, script, soma, notepad++

Estou tentando criar um script em C# para um Plugin no Notepad++, onde o objetivo é somar todos os valores dentro das tags `<ValorDesconto>`, `<ValorCancelamento>` e `<ValorTotalLiquido>` do arquivo XML que estiver aberto e exibir o resultado.

Apenas para conhecimento, o Plugin dentro do Notepad++ se chama **Automation Scripts**, segue:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores das tags **SEMPRE** são formatados apenas com duas casas decimais, então para um valor de produto de R$21.347,10 (exemplo), no XML aparecerá como **21347,10**.

Este é um exemplo do XML:

```
<Produtos>
<Produto>
<Descricao>ESMALTE</Descricao>
<Quantidade>2,00</Quantidade>
<Unidade>UN</Unidade>
<ValorDesconto>2,00</ValorDesconto>
<ValorAcrescimo>0,00</ValorAcrescimo>
<ValorCancelamento>3,00</ValorCancelamento>
<ValorTotalLiquido>23,80</ValorTotalLiquido>
</Produto>

<Produto>
<Descricao>PINCEL</Descricao>
<Quantidade>5,00</Quantidade>
<Unidade>UN</Unidade>
<ValorDesconto>3,00</ValorDesconto>
<ValorAcrescimo>0,00</ValorAcrescimo>
<ValorCancelamento>8,00</ValorCancelamento>
<ValorTotalLiquido>32,10</ValorTotalLiquido>
</Produto>
</Produtos>
```

Dentro do arquivo XML a tag `<Produto>` (dentro de `<Produtos>`) repete diversas vezes, um para cada item, o mesmo vale para a tag `<Produtos>` que repete várias vezes também. Neste exemplo, o script teria que somar as tags que mencionei e retornar o valor de R$71,90.

Segue abaixo meu código em C# que foi feito por um membro aqui da comunidade mas que está retornando sempre o valor "R$0" como podem ver na imagem em seguida.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NppScripts;

public class Script : NppScript
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        string path = Npp.Editor.GetCurrentFilePath();
        MessageBox.Show(path);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
       
        string xpath = "Produtos/Produto";
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        decimal values = 0;
        
        foreach(XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
        {
            decimal valorDesconto = Decimal.Parse(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode(".//ValorDesconto").InnerText.Replace(',','.'));
            decimal valorCancelamento = Decimal.Parse(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode(".//ValorCancelamento").InnerText.Replace(',','.'));
            decimal valorLiquido =  Decimal.Parse(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode(".//ValorLiquido").InnerText.Replace(',','.'));
            values += valorDesconto + valorCancelamento + valorLiquido;
        }
        string result = "R$" + values.ToString().Replace('.',',');
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde está o erro no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue o código C# que utilizei:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NppScripts;

public class Script : NppScript
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        string path = Npp.Editor.GetCurrentFilePath();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
       
        XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("Mensagem/Ecf/DadosReducaoZ/TotalizadoresParciais/TotalizadorParcial/ProdutosServicos/Produto");
        decimal values = 0;
        
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in nodes)
        {
          string desconto = childNode.SelectSingleNode("ValorDesconto").InnerText;
          string descontoReplaced = desconto.Replace(',', '.');
          decimal descontoParsed = Decimal.Parse(descontoReplaced);
          
          string cancelamento = childNode.SelectSingleNode("ValorCancelamento").InnerText;
          string cancelamentoReplaced = cancelamento.Replace(',', '.');
          decimal cancelamentoParsed = Decimal.Parse(cancelamentoReplaced);
          
          string totalliquido = childNode.SelectSingleNode("ValorTotalLiquido").InnerText;
          string totalliquidoReplaced = totalliquido.Replace(',', '.');
          decimal totalliquidoParsed = Decimal.Parse(totalliquidoReplaced);
          
          values += totalliquidoParsed + cancelamentoParsed + descontoParsed;
        }
        string result = "R$" + values.ToString().Replace('.',',');
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

Note que no `root.SelectNodes` tive que adicionar todas as tags Pai anteriores a tag `<Produto>`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma mais simples é usar a classe `XDocument`, que permite tratar usar métodos do `Linq` no `xml`, o que torna as operações muito mais simples.

Documentação: [system.xml.linq.xdocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-BR/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-5.0)

Pode fazer assim por exemplo:

```
var somaValorDesconto = doc.Descendants("ValorDesconto")
            .Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value))
            .Sum();
```

Basicamente, seleciona todos os nodes "ValorDesconto", e retorna convertido para `double`, e a seguir soma.

Aqui porém temos um problema, ao converter a `string` (x.Value é do tipo `string`) para `double` teremos uma erro de formato, pois o `Parse` espera o número com ponto e não vírgula nos decimais. Isso poderia ser resolvido com um `Replace` para substituir vírgula por ponto:

```
var somaValorDesconto = doc.Descendants("ValorDesconto")
            .Select(x => double.Parse(x.Value.Replace(",", ".")))
            .Sum();
```

Ainda assim, caso venha alguma valor inválido, o `Parse` pode dar erro, então a melhor opição é usar o `TryParse`, que caso não seja possível converter, não dá erro:

```
var valorDesconto = doc.Descendants("ValorDesconto")
            .Select(x => double.TryParse(x.Value, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out var value) ? value : 0)
            .Sum();
```

Para explicar: `double.TryParse(x.Value, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out var value)` isso retorna true se conseguiu converter e false se não. Além disso, se converteu, a variável `value` vai ter o valor convertido, então a expressão completa vai retornar `value` se converteu ou `0` se deu algum erro, e o `culture` é a cultura "pt-BR", para tratar a vírgula como sinal de decimais.

O código ficaria assim:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR");

var valorDesconto = doc.Descendants("ValorDesconto")
    .Select(x => double.TryParse(x.Value, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out var value) ? value : 0)
    .Sum();

var valorCancelamento = doc.Descendants("ValorCancelamento")
    .Select(x => double.TryParse(x.Value, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out var value) ? value : 0)
    .Sum();

var valorLiquido = doc.Descendants("ValorTotalLiquido")
    .Select(x => double.TryParse(x.Value, NumberStyles.Float, culture, out var value) ? value : 0)
    .Sum();

var valorTotal = valorDesconto + valorCancelamento + valorLiquido;

var result = string.Concat("R$ ",valorTotal.ToString("0.00", culture));
```

Pode ser visto funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kLZLqg

Comment: eu substituí o meu código pelo seu, porém aqui não funcionou e retornou erro. O que pode ser? Coloquei no imgur: https://imgur.com/a/iY1TSZ6